# Only switch screens if credentials are correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Right now with my current code, I have it setup so if the user enters the correct credentials it switches screens via a custom segue. But the problem is that if the user enters incorrect credentials it still switches screens but a alert letting them know the credentials are wrong pops up which is all I want to happen. Here is my project: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=260tkrb%3E&s=8#.U8g6S41dXno

Now I know, it's not a problem with Xcode, it's actually how my code is setup.

Comment: I have the segue linked from the login button to the screen below it.

Comment: @Varosion It's not really the code that's faulty. It's actually a segue I have linked like this: http://imgur.com/5etjCEm So no matter what when the login button is pressed, the screen changes. Then, in my ViewController.m I have this code: http://pastebin.com/9pqGnHEV which is set up so if the credentials are correct and they press login the screen switches due to the segue linked from the login button and if the credentials do not match, the alert pops up.

Comment: @Varosion So what I want to do is only if the credentials are correct the custom segue works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag the segue from the view controller, not the button. Then give it a name (like "login") and only call it in code once the user credentials are verified:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
```

Apple docs for `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: